# How to create curved widget without using border-radius in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a beginner of flutter development. I'm trying to create a curved widget using the border-radius component, but I'm not able to create an exact mockup screen. Please guide me on how to draw the curved widget. Here I have attached my mockup sample.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You should also post what you've tried so far and how you're attempting this.

Comment: You might want to consider [How to reduce image size on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253403/3290339)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example how you can achieve it using `CustomClipper`

```
class ClippingApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ClipPath(
        clipper: CurvedBottomClipper(),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.lightGreen,
          height: 250.0,
          child: Center(
              child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
            child: Text(
              "Curved View",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CurvedBottomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    // I've taken approximate height of curved part of view
    // Change it if you have exact spec for it
    final roundingHeight = size.height * 3 / 5;

    // this is top part of path, rectangle without any rounding
    final filledRectangle =
        Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, size.width, size.height - roundingHeight);

    // this is rectangle that will be used to draw arc
    // arc is drawn from center of this rectangle, so it's height has to be twice roundingHeight
    // also I made it to go 5 units out of screen on left and right, so curve will have some incline there
    final roundingRectangle = Rect.fromLTRB(
        -5, size.height - roundingHeight * 2, size.width + 5, size.height);

    final path = Path();
    path.addRect(filledRectangle);

    // so as I wrote before: arc is drawn from center of roundingRectangle
    // 2nd and 3rd arguments are angles from center to arc start and end points
    // 4th argument is set to true to move path to rectangle center, so we don't have to move it manually
    path.arcTo(roundingRectangle, pi, -pi, true);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    // returning fixed 'true' value here for simplicity, it's not the part of actual question, please read docs if you want to dig into it
    // basically that means that clipping will be redrawn on any changes
    return true;
  }
}
```

And this is what you will get with this code: [image: Curved rectangle screenshot]

Comment: You might want to consider [How to reduce image size on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253403/3290339)

Answer (score 0):

You can have circular containers, you can experiment how to position it on your screen

```
Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 500,
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.green,
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
  ),
  child: Text('Curved View'),
  alignment: Alignment.center,
)
```

Comment: true, force of habit having coded in multiple OOP languages. //EDIT comment left in response to user whom has now deleted their comment about there being no need to use 'new'..